# Bounded increasing differentiable and right-continuous function is Hölder continuous for some exponent $\gamma$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, statistics, holder-spaces

Consider for arbitrary $\gamma=\alpha+\beta, \alpha=0,1, \ldots, 0<\beta \leq 1$, the Hölder class $\Lambda_\gamma$ of functions $g(y), y \geq 0$ having finite norm

$$
|| g ||_{\gamma}=\sup _{y \geq 0}|g(y)|+\sup _{x, y \geq 0} \frac{\left|g^{(\alpha)}(x)-g^{(\alpha)}(y)\right|}{|x-y|^\beta} .
$$

Now consider $g$ to be a bounded between $0$ and $1$, increasing, differentiable and right-continuous function. Does this imply $g \in \Lambda_{\gamma}$?

My thoughts: I think this is not necessarily the case because one can think of $g$ as a cumulative distribution function that has density (thus differentiable) and*emphasized text* which is clearly right continuous. Then if $g^{\prime}$ is unbounded we cannot find any $\gamma$ such that $|| g ||_{\gamma} < \infty$. I think the above conditions only imply local Lipschitz continuity and since we are dealing with cumulative distribution functions which have density we clearly have uniform continuity as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942396/show-that-the-cumulative-distribution-function-is-uniformly-continuous).

Any help is highly appreciated!